# Why bother with multi-layer RIA if Internet now is fast enougth to do "traditional" fat client C/S?

Tags: ajax, client-server, rich-internet-application

Why bother with multi-layer RIA if Internet now is fast enougth to do "traditional" fat client C/S?

What just use a plain C++ / Delphi / Oracle Forms / JAVA-Swing application talking directly to RDBMS thru Internet?

A very complex compiled exe program in Delphi is about 10MB, that amount of code downloads in a couple of minutes in a decent 1MB ADSL connection.

After all what is what we are doing with AJAX / BlazeDS / JSON / etc pushing thru http/https protocol but with a lot of layers and a lot of points of failure...

Comments please...

Comment: Please update the question to clarify the points for a "traditional" client against a web client -- right now your question sounds rather argumentative.  Otherwise, please mark this question as a community wiki, as in its current form it is simply an invitation to a discussion. Finally, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

First a bit about terminology, what you refer as "traditional fat clients" are probably desktop software. Web applications are often written as thin clients, but they can also be written as fat clients. A fat client rich internet application are client centric, which means that a lot of the work is done in the client (browser). Fat client RIAs can be written with the help of technologies such as AJAX or Adobe Flash.

To compare the advantages of web based applications over desktop software:

**Maintainability:** One of the advantages of web based applications is the maintainability of them. You only have to make one installation of the application and then it is directly available for all users. Same goes for updating of the software, you only need to update the software on the server and then you can be sure that every single user is using the latest version of the software. This eliminates the need to update individual installments of the application on the users' computers.

**Security:** There are two positive security implication in using web based application. As said previously, you only need to update the software in one place. This means that the users always have the most up-to-date version of the software in use, thus eliminating the problem of people using outdated, vulnerable version of the application.

What is more important, is that fat client applications are insecure. They expose application logic and possibly sensitive data such as database credentials. Fat clients can be reverse engineered and attacks can be crafted based on the gained information. For an application to be truly secure, the application logic should stay on the server and the client should be thin and only server as a presentation layer for the information handled in the application. Do remember the exposure of application logic can also affect rich internet applications. It is easy to write RIA in a way that it exposes application logic. Hence it is important to remember that the application's state should always stay on the server, the browser is, as said, only means for presenting the data. In other words, both web based applications and desktop applications can be (in)secure, I'd just say that there is a greater risk of pushing application logic to the client when writing desktop software.

**Platform independent:** Web based applications are platform independent (with the exception in application that use platform specific functionality, such as activex). This means that your users can be using the application from a mac, a windows or a linux computer, it doesn't matter. Of course, it is unfortunately easy to create web applications that do not work/only works on specific browsers, such as Internet Explorer. Although, it is much easier to make a web application cross-browser compatible than to write a desktop software to be truly cross-platform compatible.

**Accessability:** If you are connected to the Internet/Intranet, you have access to the application. It doesn't matter if you have borrowed your friend's laptop or if you are sitting by your desktop computer, you still have access to the application since it doesn't require you to install anything on the computer. Just browse to the application URL.